# how to change unicode font colors

Tags: html, css, unicode

im trying to make a green checkmark with unicode.

```
<td><div style="color:green;">hi</div></td>
```

the code above produces green text: hi.

```
<td><div style="color:green;">&#10004;</div></td>
```

the code above produces a black checkmark. for some reason the checkmark doesn't change its color, even though on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rKMw8/2/) jsfiddle it does change its color to green. how can i fix this"?

Comment: the exact code works in jsfiddle, but for some reason not in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Try using the font `Segoe UI Symbol`.

`<td><div style="color:green; font-family:"Segoe UI Symbol">&#10004;</div></td>`

```html
<td><div style="color:green; font-family:"Segoe UI Symbol"">&#10004;</div></td>
```

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1180157